Finding gene duplications in bacteria
I would like to know if there is an easy tool to find how many copies of a certain gene are present in all available bacterial genomes.
For example, which bacterial genomes contain one or more copies of Superoxide dismutase.

Simply use RNAseq tools such as EdgeR, each gene must be a separate entity, e.g. separate fasta entry for this approach. This is one approach, there are lots. Probably a good idea to provide more details.

What is the dataset you are working from? Are you working from finished, annotated genomes, raw sequencing data, de novo assemblies, ...?
The simplest answer would be to go to a genome database such as KEGG and look up the relevant genes. MicrobesOnline and COGs are other resource I've used, but there are likely newer ones.
If you simply query the gene in such a database, you should get a list of entries and the relevant genomes that they're in, and you then get the copy number of the gene in the genome for free. Here is such a page on MicrobesOnline.
The one caution that I have is to really understand the orthology of the gene you're interested in.

Prokka is an easy-to-use pipeline for the annotation of bacterial genomes. Here is the link to the GitHub page: https://github.com/tseemann/prokka
nic
